# Same day passports

Tags: passports, us-citizens

According to the [State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/services/expedited.html), you can get a passport "right now" if you *have a life or death emergency*.

[This site](http://samedaypassport-visa.com/) advertises same day passports for "*urgently departing citizens*" but doesn't mention the life or death thing.

*Can* you get a same day passport, even if it's not a real, honest to goodness, emergency? The non-government website makes it seem like you can, but I guess that's a matter of interpretation.

Comment: Have you contacted Sameday Passport?  If they operate quickly (same day) I would expect their query response to be prompt also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official requirements to get a passport at a passport agency](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/information/where-to-apply/agencies/san-francisco.html) are that you are "traveling internationally in less than 2 weeks or need to get a foreign visa within 4 weeks." You normally need an appointment, but [at least some agencies are known to take walk-ins](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/26739/13650) as [an unadvertised policy](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/01/11/how-to-get-passport-fast_n_6436482.html), but [you may be waiting a very long time](http://www.hirahim.com/blog/2011/08/03/how-to-renew-an-expired-passport-in-nine-hours/). You'd need proof of your upcoming travel, such as a copy of your itinerary, but don't need proof of a life-or-death emergency.

There's no guarantee that it will be the same day though; they may have you come back the next day to pick it up sometimes, such as if you don't need to travel for a few days. But they will generally be able to get you a passport before your trip, barring any issues such as problems with your documents or verifying your identity.